# Need to load all items to Observable<Hero[]> before the users add any filter

Tags: angular

How do I change the Angular 2 Tour of Heroes search component (https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/eplnkr.html) so it brings all items on init (show all Heroes on page load) and when the filter is provided it makes a new request to the service getting the filtered results into the heroes variable?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';

import { Observable }        from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }           from 'rxjs/Subject';

// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

import { HeroSearchService } from './hero-search.service';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-search',
  templateUrl: './hero-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-search.component.css' ],
  providers: [HeroSearchService]
})
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(
    private heroSearchService: HeroSearchService,
    private router: Router) {}

  // Push a search term into the observable stream.
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroes = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)        // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
      .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time the term changes
        // return the http search observable
        ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
        // or the observable of empty heroes if there was no search term
        : Observable.of<Hero[]>([]))
      .catch(error => {
        // TODO: add real error handling
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of<Hero[]>([]);
      });
  }

  gotoDetail(hero: Hero): void {
    let link = ['/detail', hero.id];
    this.router.navigate(link);
  }
}
```

Currently is just sends a request after providing the search term.

Comment: So you want to see all heroes instead **Top Heroes**, did I get this right or I misunderstood your question ?

Comment: I don't need to change the **Top Heroes** behaviour, I just need to show the list of all Heroes by default and when something is typed, the list is filtered.

Comment: I tried adding a call to `this.search("");` inside `ngOnInit()`, but nothing seems to be happening (the service is not executed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello_

basically this is the main place that you can do the change to get it work:

```
.switchMap(
    term => term    
    ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
    : Observable.of<Hero[]>([]))  // <----- HERE if term is empty string you want to return all Heroes instead of empty collection
```

to achieve this you can inject **HeroService** from **hero.service.ts** which has method **getHeroes()** which is returning all the heroes.

So now we can change the above piece of code to look like this:

```
// First don't forget to inject HeroService and don't forget to import it too
constructor(
    private heroSearchService: HeroSearchService,
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private router: Router) {}

// Then the ngOnInit() will look like this
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroes = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)        
      .distinctUntilChanged()  
      .switchMap(term => term  
        ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
        : this.heroService.getHeroes()) // <--- HERE if term is empty return all heroes
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of<Hero[]>([]);
      });

      // Wait for 100 ms before loading all heroes ...
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.search('');
      }, 100); 
}
```

> I tried adding a call to this.search(""); inside ngOnInit()

Yes, we need this to load all heroes, but give it a small delay otherwise nothing shows.

Let me know if everything is clear :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But don't we have a way to call the `search()` method without the setTimeout?

Comment: Well this looks like a timing issue to me and seems fine to call it with `setTimeout()`. Other thing that I'm thinking right now is to implement `AfterViewInit` and call `this.search('')` inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, but this is not tested you can try it and report what is the result

Comment: That looks like a more "elegant" solution. Thanks

Comment: should I understand that it works :)       You are welcome

Comment: Works perfectly :)